# Views References

Tags: views, 8

I have a view that is shown in a block. This view-block shows nodes that have the same taxonomy term selected than the host node (the node thats shows the block).

Well that's the plan.

Node A
  - has a field "my_tax_ref_field" (tax_term = 4)

The view should list...
  - nodes with the field "my_tax_ref_field" (tax_term = 4)

I am lost...

I tried to set conditional filter on the node id. Then I set a relationship on the field "my_tax_ref_field". I thought then the normal filter could pick up the relationship to filter for the term_id.

But it just does not work like that.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you'll need the _field comparison_ filter for this. Add both `my_tax_ref_field` fields to the fields section (with and without reference), and hide them from display. Then add the field comparison filter and provide it with both fields.

Comment: field comparison filter? cannot find this filter in views

Comment: You seem to be right... It used to be in Drupal 7, so I assumed it would be in 8 as well. But I cannot find it either...

Comment: actually it's a lot easier than I thought. Have a look at my threads answer.

There is no logic... involved... however.. its works :)

Comment: Nice, glad you've figured this out :)

Answer (score 1):

ok... it's easier than expected:

Choose " Provide default value " as action to take if arg is not given.
Choose Term ID from URL"
Check "Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks"
:)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162196/create-a-drupal-view-that-loads-all-articles-that-share-any-one-taxonomy-term-c?rq=1